# GetQueuedCompletionStatus cant be running in a timer?

Tags: c#, .net

os: win7 32bit

.net:3.5

I used below function(which runs in a thread) to do job event handle, everything goes ok.

```
private void JobEventThread()
{
    uint jobEvent = 0;
    UIntPtr comKey;
    IntPtr Overlapped;
    bool bGoOn = true;
    while (bGoOn 
        && Kernel32Dll.GetQueuedCompletionStatus
                (m_hiocp, out jobEvent, out comKey, out Overlapped, Win32Define.INFINITE))
    {
        if (comKey.ToUInt32() == completeKey)
        {
            switch (jobEvent)
            {
                case Win32Define.JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS:
                    int pid = Overlapped.ToInt32();
                    if (NewProcessEvent != null){NewProcessEvent(pid, GetProcessNameById(pid));}
                    break;

                case Win32Define.JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS:
                    if (ExitProcessEvent != null) { ExitProcessEvent(Overlapped.ToInt32()); }
                    break;

                case Win32Define.JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO:
                    if (ExitJobEvent != null) { ExitJobEvent(); }
                    bGoOn = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i tried DispatchTimer to do such thing, GetQueuedCompletionStatus always return false.

```
private void JobEventThread(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uint jobEvent = 0;
    UIntPtr comKey;
    IntPtr Overlapped;
    if (Kernel32Dll.GetQueuedCompletionStatus
                (m_hiocp, out jobEvent, out comKey, out Overlapped, 0))
    {
        if (comKey.ToUInt32() == completeKey)
        {
            switch (jobEvent)
            {
                case Win32Define.JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS:
                    int pid = Overlapped.ToInt32();
                    if (NewProcessEvent != null){NewProcessEvent(pid, GetProcessNameById(pid));}
                    break;

                case Win32Define.JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS:
                    if (ExitProcessEvent != null) { ExitProcessEvent(Overlapped.ToInt32()); }
                    break;

                case Win32Define.JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO:
                    if (ExitJobEvent != null) { ExitJobEvent(); }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want my event come from a thread, that will let my program complex!

Comment: Did you try to call `GetLastError` (e.g. using  `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`), perhaps it has useful error information?

Comment: @Marcus there is no error, just false